# The parameter came from broadcast receiver constructor is always nullable

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I want to update my main activity UI in my foreground service with broadcast receiver. In BroadcastReceiver.OnReceive method,I passed the instance of main activity,but it is always nullable. How can I fix it? Many thanks in advance!

In my broadcast receiver:

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Core.Music music = intent.GetParcelableExtra("selectedMusic") as Core.Music;

        mMainActivity.mTxtSongName.Text = Core.MusicHelper.GetTitleAndAuthor(music.Title);
        mMainActivity.mTxtAuthorName.Text = Core.MusicHelper.GetTitleAndAuthor(music.Author);

        System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
        {
            string imageUrl = music.Url.Replace(@"\", "").Replace("http", "https");
            var task = Core.MusicHelper.GetSongPic(imageUrl, 35, 35);
            var pic = task.Result;

            if (pic != null)
            {
                mMainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    mMainActivity.mImageViewSongPic.SetImageBitmap(pic);
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

In my service:

```
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        Core.Music music = intent.GetParcelableExtra("selectedMusic") as Core.Music;
        BroadcastStarted(music);

        //To start the service

        return StartCommandResult.NotSticky;
    }
```

In my MainActivity.OnResume:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
mReceive = new Service.Boradcast.MusicChangedBroadcastReceiver() { mMainActivity=this};
RegisterReceiver(mReceive,filter);
```

Comment: By `always nullable` do you mean `always null`? On what **line of code** is it always `null`?

Comment: Most likely this `Core.Music music = intent.GetParcelableExtra("selectedMusic") as Core.Music;` is failing. Is that a valid cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you defined mMainActivity ?

however the simplest example of a reference to `MainActivity` is to use `static`

define in your `MainActivity` `OnCreate()` method:

```
public static MainActivity Instance;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
  {
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
     ...
    Instance = this;
  }
```

then call in your broadcast receiver

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Core.Music music = intent.GetParcelableExtra("selectedMusic") as Core.Music;

    MainActivity.Instance.mTxtSongName.Text = Core.MusicHelper.GetTitleAndAuthor(music.Title);
    MainActivity.Instance.mTxtAuthorName.Text = Core.MusicHelper.GetTitleAndAuthor(music.Author);

    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        string imageUrl = music.Url.Replace(@"\", "").Replace("http", "https");
        var task = Core.MusicHelper.GetSongPic(imageUrl, 35, 35);
        var pic = task.Result;

        if (pic != null)
        {
            MainActivity.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                MainActivity.Instance.mImageViewSongPic.SetImageBitmap(pic);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Or pass MainActivity as a parameter to the constructor ：

in your MainActivity.OnResume():

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
mReceive = new Service.Boradcast.MusicChangedBroadcastReceiver(this);
RegisterReceiver(mReceive,filter);
```

then in your broadcast receiver：

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class MusicChangedBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver
{
    public MainActivity mMainActivity;
    public MusicChangedBroadcastReceiver()
    {

    }
    public MusicChangedBroadcastReceiver(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.mMainActivity= activity;
    }

 public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
    Core.Music music = intent.GetParcelableExtra("selectedMusic") as Core.Music;

    mMainActivity.mTxtSongName.Text = Core.MusicHelper.GetTitleAndAuthor(music.Title);
    mMainActivity.mTxtAuthorName.Text = Core.MusicHelper.GetTitleAndAuthor(music.Author);

    System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
    {
        string imageUrl = music.Url.Replace(@"\", "").Replace("http", "https");
        var task = Core.MusicHelper.GetSongPic(imageUrl, 35, 35);
        var pic = task.Result;

        if (pic != null)
        {
            mMainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                mMainActivity.mImageViewSongPic.SetImageBitmap(pic);
            });
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I passed the main activity as a parameter to the constructor as well,the main activity is still  null. perhaps the instance created in main activity on resume is not the same with the instance created in broadcast started?

Comment: By the way, I don't think the state field in main activity would work.

Comment: @LiuFeng have you tested with my code above?The variable name is wrong, it should be mMainAcitivity

Comment: I tested that it worked with a simple broadcast example

Comment: @LiuFeng ok,happy coding!

Comment: You tested the static field code or the constructor code?

Comment: Your first solution works well for me, but the second one failed. I still do not know why. But luckily my problem has been solved. Thanks!